# find value in dynamic created varchar array C++

Tags: c++, arrays

so i'm running my head against a wall at the Moment. I want to create a dynamic array, which can contain numbers or text - but most likely numbers.

At the Moment i'm using:

```
string test[];
```

for that purpose.

Okay, now the thing is. I want to dynamically fill the array, if the Element is not already in the array. I've tryed googling solution, but most of them came up with vector, which wouldn't work in this case, because the array can be any size.

Again:

Check if the Element is in the Array, that can be empty or not
If Element is not in the Array, put it in.

Anybody got a Solution for this, please? Would be very thankfully!

---

Thank you very much for all those comments and answers. I just noticed one major difference from between what i found in the net and what you guys posted. if i use `test[]` it won't work, but if i use `test{}` everything is fine. Can somebody maybe explain me why is that?

Comment: Why would `vector` not work?

Comment: "the array can be any size." That's why you should use `std::vector`.

Comment: Why not using `std::set` for that?

Comment: Agree, just use std::set <std::string > and insert what ever values comes... the value is unique by definition of set...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if I understood correctly you're trying to get an dynamic array which changes its size depending on how much elements are in there? Well then use `vector`. It does excatly this! And its pretty fast and the C++ standard for tasks like that.

Using a `vector`also allows you to use `std::find`. So to fullfill your task do something like that:

```
std::vector<std::string> test{"Hello"};

if (std::find(test.begin(), test.end(), "World!") == test.end())
    test.push_back("World!");
```

Or even better, use `std::set` wich only allows unique elements:

```
std::set<std::string> test{"Hello"};
test.insert("World"); // works
test.insert("Hello"); // won't work
```

If you realy want to use an array then I would recommend you to write a template class to manage the array and then allocate the array on the heap.

```
template<typename T>
class Array
{
    private:
        T *data;
        unsigned int size;
        unsigned int index;

    public:
        Array() 
        {
            size = 100;
            index = 0;
            data = new T[size];
        }

        ~Array() 
        {
            delete[] data;
        }

        void push_back(const T& val)
        {
            if (index == size)
            {   // reallocate data if there is no memory left to store val
                std::vector<T> tmp(data, data + size);
                delete[] data;
                size += 100;
                data = new T[size];
                for (size_t i = 0; i < tmp.size(); i++)
                    data[i] = tmp[i];
                data[index++] = val;
            }
            else
            {
                data[index++] = val; 
            }
        }

        T& operator[](const unsigned int& i)
        {
            if (i >= size)
                throw std::runtime_error("i out of bounds");
            return data[i];
        }
};
```

You then need to search in the array for an existing value, and if you couldn't find it use `push_back` to push the value into the array. Or use the subscript operator `[]` like you're used to.